# Google Views in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'

Tags: javascript, iframe

```
<iframe src='https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=https://docs.google.com/document/d/125CJmmlBfy7UgfYuBAmb1_HSCuyz8NV133361KTK1SE/export?format%3Dpdf&id=125CJmmlBfy7UgfYuBAmb1_HSCuyz8NV133361KTK1SE&embedded=false'  frameborder='0'></iframe>
```

after this code I have next error

> ```
> Refused to display 'https://docs.google.com/a/myrussiaonline.ru/viewer?url=https://docs.google.…ormat%3Dpdf&id=125CJmmlBfy7UgfYuBAmb1_HSCuyz8NV133361KTK1SE&embedded=false' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.
> ```

If I set

```
<iframe src='https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=https://docs.google.com/document/d/125CJmmlBfy7UgfYuBAmb1_HSCuyz8NV133361KTK1SE/export?format%3Dpdf&id=125CJmmlBfy7UgfYuBAmb1_HSCuyz8NV133361KTK1SE&embedded=true'  frameborder='0'></iframe>
```

Then, all fine

Can I set `&embedded=false` and have correct render without error?

Thanks

Comment: did you find a way to do this?

Answer (score 8):

The only way I've found to get the Google Docs Viewer to work in an iframe is:

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/viewer?srcid=[YOUR_FILE'S_ID_HERE]&pid=explorer&efh=false&a=v&chrome=false&embedded=true" width="800" height="600" style="border: none;"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this tutorial-

https://www.youtube.com/embed/A5SkbcId-v0

U should have your answer.

### Update-

According to Google Policy, if u like to have your document viewed with a iFrame, then `embedded=true` should be in the **URL**.

Demo Code-

```html
<iframe src='https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=https://docs.google.com/document/d/125CJmmlBfy7UgfYuBAmb1_HSCuyz8NV133361KTK1SE/export?format%3Dpdf&id=125CJmmlBfy7UgfYuBAmb1_HSCuyz8NV133361KTK1SE&embedded=true'  frameborder='0'></iframe>
```

Comment: This doesn't work anymore -- run your code snippet to view "No preview available."

Answer (score 1):

First you should go to your document on google drive :

1. click file
2. publish to the web
3. embed
4. publish

You will get the code of the iframe you can use it to visualize your spreadsheet without the possibility to edit it

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not, this parameter is specify that source would be embedded. And the idea behind using it is to avoid [clickjacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking) attacks