# SameOrigin Policy interfering with Google Docs

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, iframe, same-origin-policy

I was hosting google docs in an Iframe a few months ago to allow users to pull some PDFS down, but recently I noticed that the iframes I used to show the PDFs are throwing console errors for the SameOrigin Policy preventing the documents from loading. Is there any way around this?

I built the website using asp.net mvc

It would be a handful of iframes to the effect of:

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/SamplePDFURL" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

The error looks like

Refused to display https://docs.google.com/*SamplePDFURL* in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `&embedded=true` to the end of your URL as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26079476/google-views-in-a-frame-because-it-set-x-frame-options-to-sameorigin?rq=1).

Comment: Other resources that might be useful:  
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/03/30/combating-clickjacking-with-x-frame-options.aspx  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options

Comment: The suggestion was able to render the Viewer but the PDF was purely the encoded version and I couldnt interpret it using the first suggestions. I stumbled upon http://www.benschersten.com/blog/2014/04/embedding-a-pdf-from-drive-into-a-blog/ which got me a different but still effective format.